How do I test a long running Android WorkManager CoroutineWorker with constraints?
How do I test a long running Android work request with constraints? Following the official documentation I can use a  TestDriver to set the conditions met. However, shortly after starting the work, during doWork, my CoroutineWorker gets cancelled by the android system any way.
A full example demonstrating this is below:
package my.package

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.work.Configuration
import androidx.work.Constraints
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.ForegroundInfo
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder
import androidx.work.WorkInfo
import androidx.work.WorkManager
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import androidx.work.testing.SynchronousExecutor
import androidx.work.testing.WorkManagerTestInitHelper
import kotlinx.coroutines.CancellationException
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

public class LongRunningWorkerWithNotification(context: Context, parameters: WorkerParameters)
  : CoroutineWorker(context, parameters) {
  override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    try {
      val foregroundInfo = createForegroundInfo()
      setForeground(foregroundInfo)
      delay(1000)
      return Result.success()
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
      return Result.failure()
    }
  }

  private fun createForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "MY_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID")
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .build()
    return ForegroundInfo(0, notification)
  }


}

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
internal class DemonstrateWorkTestProblem {

  val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

  @Before
  fun setup() {
    val config =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
            .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
            .build()

    // Initialize WorkManager for instrumentation tests.
    WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)
  }


  @Test
  fun testLongRunningWorkerWithNotification() = runBlocking {

    val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<LongRunningWorkerWithNotification>()
         .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().setRequiresCharging(true).build())
        .build()
    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    workManager.enqueue(request)
    val testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver(context)
    testDriver?.setAllConstraintsMet(request.id)
    delay(3000) // give it a chance to run
    val workInfo = workManager.getWorkInfoById(request.id).get()
    assert(workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED)

  }
}

Through experimentation I have discovered that making it a short running work (i.e. not calling setForeground) or removing the constraint I can make the test pass. However, in the real world application code that I need to test, the Worker needs to be long running and needs to have constraints applied.
